# Puppet noop When Executable does not exist yet

Tags: puppet

The following is a *simplified* manifest I am running:

```
package {'ruby2.4':
  ensure => installed
}

exec { "gem2.4_install_bundler":
  command => "/usr/bin/gem2.4 install bundler",
  require => Package['ruby2.4']
}
```

Puppet apply runs this manifest correctly i.e

1. installs ruby2.4 package (which includes gem2.4)
2. Installs bundler using gem2.4

However, puppet apply --noop FAILS because puppet cannot find the executable '/usr/bin/gem2.4' because ruby2.4 is not installed with --noop.

My question is if there is a standard way to test a scenario like this with puppet apply --noop? To validate that my puppet manifest is executing correctly?

It occurs to me that I may have to parse the output and validate the order of the executions. If this is the case, is there a standard way/tool for this?

A last resort is a very basic check that the puppet at least runs, which can be determined with the --detailed-exitcodes option.  (a code different to 1).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rspec-puppet](http://rspec-puppet.com/) is the standard tool for that level of verification. It can build a catalog from the manifest (e.g. for a class, defined type, or host) and then you can write tests to verify the contents.

In your case you could verify that the `package` resource exists, that the `exec` resource exists, and verify the ordering between them. This would be just as effective as running the agent with `--noop` mode and parsing the output - but easier and cheaper to run.

rspec-puppet works best with modules, so assuming you follow the setup for your module from the website (adding `rspec-puppet` to your `Gemfile`, running `rspec-puppet-init`), and let's say this is in a class called `ruby24`, a simple spec in `spec/classes/ruby24_spec.rb` would be:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'ruby24' do
  it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }
  it { is_expected.to contain_package('ruby2.4').with_ensure('installed') }
  it { is_expected.to contain_exec('gem2.4_install_bundler').with_command('/usr/bin/gem2.4 install bundler') }
  it { is_expected.to contain_exec('gem2.4_install_bundler').that_requires('Package[ruby2.4]') }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for a very useful and informative response